# Flip shell arguments

Tags: shell

What is the shortest way to write Haskell's `flip` for the shell?
`flip` should switch the first 2 arguments of a command.

Example:
`cp a b` should be equivalent to `flip cp b a`.

Comment: You can try also try on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: `shell` tag implies only posix compatible shell. Maybe consider tagging `bash`. Note that GNU `cp` has `-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY` option that allows the destination to be first argument.

Comment: Can you assume the `flip` takes at least 3 arguments?

Comment: `sh` implies a POSIX shell; `[shell]` could conceivably include things like PowerShell and question involving the implementation of a custom command shell.

Comment: The description of `shell` tag is `Without a specific tag, a portable (POSIX-compliant) solution should be assumed` so I always assumed that

Comment: The description probably needs to be updated :)

Comment: If the solution is elegant, I'll use the shell it works on.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that you generally *don't* want to flip the arguments, at least not without ignoring options.

Comment: The "type" of a command is more fluid that your typical Haskell function, really closer to `[String] -> a` than `String -> String -> b`.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell supports it, you can use a substring operator; in `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh`, it looks like `${@:4}` to expand the 4th and subsequent arguments.

```
flip () { "$1" "$3" "$2" "${@:4}"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just save the first 3 arguments, shift by 3 and properly flip them when calling the callback.

```
flip(){ local a=$1 b=$2 c=$3;shift 3;"$a" "$c" "$b" "$@";}
```